# How do I preview a xls file fetched via XHR?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm fetch files with a header `Content-Disposition:attachment;`. Is there a way I can allow render the response in the browser to allow the guest to preview it before downloading?

Comment: will need a library either at server or client side js to parse it to html